# How to convert this Apache RewriteRule in Nginx?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, nginx, reverse-proxy

I've got this RewriteRule, And I can't make it work with nginx :

```
RewriteRule  ^/espace-annonceurs/@@contenu-des-espaces-annonceurs http://mywebsite.com/@@contenu-des-espaces-annonceurs [L,P]
```

The Proxy is because it make an ajax request.

I've tried a lot of things, with location, proxy_pass, rewrite, and so on...

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Is `@@contenu-des-espaces-annonceurs` a directory or just a single page? Does `@@` mean something special?

Comment: it's just a page, the @@ means it's a view of the CMS, so, it's not important.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need proxy request to your host to some other host. That's job for proxy module. The simplest config would be like this:

```
location /espace-annonceurs/@@contenu-des-espaces-annonceurs {
    proxy_pass http://mywebsite.com/@@contenu-des-espaces-annonceurs;
}
```

Probably you'll need some `proxy_set_header`s directive.

Read documentation http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at this, and particulary at the proxy_set_header

Answer (score -1):

So a simple rewrite would do.

```
rewrite ^/(espace-annonceurs/@@contenu-des-espaces-annonceurs)$ http://example.com/$1;
```

Comment: yes, but this doesn't work because of cross-domain, that's why we have a Proxy mod on this with apache.